# Check which Blogspot sites are removed with PHP

Tags: php, curl, cron

I want to check if some Blogspot sites (more than 5000 sites) are online or has been removed by Google using PHP, cron & curl. I will use cronjob to check all the sites everyday, every hour. 
I know that curl will select specific div (e.g div with `id="header-outer"`) contents of the Blogspot site. But I'm hesitant thinking it will burden the server.

- Checking more than 5000 Blogspot site with curl every hour/every day using cronjob.
- echo status "active" if site still online or "removed" if site has been removed by Google.

Is there any way to check the status of more than 5000 Blogspot sites using curl and cronjob? A small idea might help me a lot.

Comment: If my question is very low quality, please don't down vote this but you can flag my question, It really appreciate me.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track - cURL with DomDocument would do it. If you have 5000 to check, you can afford to have a ~17 second delay between each call, which you'll need to do to avoid swamping the Blogspot servers (and getting blocked).

Comment: thanks @halfer for the response, my plan build curd php for add, edit and delete url site and show there status's site. According to you, is't enough for my case only at localhost or I should rent a hosting/vps ?

Comment: You can do this from a home computer, yes, if it is always on. Personally I'd do it from a VPS, as the response times should be faster and the internet connection more reliable, but that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. You would put all the URLs into a file, maybe call it url.txt:

```
(while read url; do if curl -s --retry 3 $url | grep 'header-outer' >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "$url: active"; else echo "$url: removed"; fi; done) < url.txt
```

You can put that into the cron entry or put that into a shell script and run the shell script. What I'm not entirely clear on is what PHP has to do with it, and the output format. If you're processing 5000 urls and only getting "active" or "removed" how do you know which ones are active and removed? I prefixed the "active" and "removed" with the URL that was provided.

Comment: Also, I don't think 5000 requests per hour will be especially burdensome on blogspot.com servers, but it's possible you might be violating a ToS or something, I can't speak to that.